# Whitelist internal address on Exchange 365 for "Potentially compromised accounts"

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, microsoft-365

I am receiving the following alert for an internal address:

> Potentially compromised account. Anomalous sending patterns were detected resulting in the user being restricted from sending mail

Ironically, it's my alerts@ address.  It's sending multiple external emails to cell phone addresses (@vtext.com, etc).

I have unblocked the address a few times following [the directions here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/removing-user-from-restricted-users-portal-after-spam?view=o365-worldwide#use-the-microsoft-365-defender-portal-to-remove-a-user-from-the-restricted-users-list), but it keeps getting flagged again.  How can I whitelist this address so it does not trigger this policy?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, the EOP will block the mailbox who sends mails too much email too quickly via Outbound spam protection in EOP. Here's a detailed explanation on [why Exchange Online Protection Blocks Email Senders](https://office365itpros.com/2020/07/27/when-exchange-online-protection-blocks-email-senders/)

To fix the issue, you could [configure outbound spam filtering in EOP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/configure-the-outbound-spam-policy?view=o365-worldwide#use-the-microsoft-365-defender-portal-to-create-outbound-spam-policies) to raise the sending limits. The default [sending limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits#sending-limits-1) in the blog for your reference.